# How do I use clocking wizard to create a slower clock for my program?

Tags: verilog, fpga, vivado

Hey guys so I'm very new to Verilog and Fpga's so sorry if I am missing something very simple. I am trying to interface an external SRAM that I would like to test for functionality. I have written this code along with a test bench to verify it. I will be trying to just simply write and read some data to make sure the device works properly. Since I will be trying to test this on a breadboard I am first attempting to lower the clk frequency at which my program will be running down from the sys clock of 100 MHz to 12 MHz using the clocking wizard IP in Vivado. The problem seems to be that my output from the clocking wizard is not working properly and will only output a single pulse at the incorrect frequency.

top.v:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module TOP(
  
    input clk,
    input btn,
    output reg[7:0] io,
    output WE,
    output OE,
    output CE_0,
    output CE_1
    );
    
    
    
   clk_wiz_0 clktwelve
   (
    // Clock out ports
    .clk_out1(clk0),     // output clk_out1
    
    // Status and control signals
    .clk_in1(clk)      // input clk_in1
);

    wire clk1 = clk0;
  
  
  
    reg output_enable;
    reg write_enable;
    reg chip_enable_low;
    reg chip_enable_high;
    reg[7:0] cnt=8'd0; 
 
always @ (posedge clk1 )
    if (btn==1)
        begin
            output_enable = 1'b0;
            write_enable = 1'b1;
            chip_enable_low = 1'b1;
            chip_enable_high = 1'b0;
            io[0] = 1'bz;
            io[1] = 1'bz;
            io[2] = 1'bz;
            io[3] = 1'bz;
            io[4] = 1'bz;
            io[5] = 1'bz;
            io[6] = 1'bz;
            io[7] = 1'bz;
        end
        else begin 
            output_enable =1'b0;
            write_enable = 1'b0;
            chip_enable_high = 1'b1;
            chip_enable_low  = 1'b0;
            if(cnt<255) cnt=cnt+1'b1;
            else cnt=8'd0;
            io=cnt;
            end  
            
assign OE = output_enable ;
assign WE = write_enable ;
assign CE_0 = chip_enable_low;
assign CE_1 = chip_enable_high;

endmodule
```

TESTBENCH:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps


module TOP_TB();

    reg clk;
    reg btn;
    wire [7:0] io;
    wire WE;
    wire OE;
    wire CE_0;
    wire CE_1;
    
    TOP testbench1 (
     .clk(clk),
     .btn(btn),
     .io(io),
     .WE(WE),
     .OE(OE), 
     .CE_0(CE_0),
     .CE_1(CE_1)
     
    );
    
initial begin 
      btn = 1;
      clk = 0;
      
      
     #200 btn = 0;
     #500000 $finish;
     end
     
 always #10 clk = ~clk;
        
 
endmodule
```

I plan to ultimately design a pcb board and test the asynchronous sram at maximum frequency of 100MHZ, any advice is helpful!

btw I am using a ARTY A7 35T

I tried this simple code to trouble shoot the problem and still can not get a clean response.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module top(

   input clk,
   output clk0
   
    );
    
  clk_wiz_0 instance1
   (
    // Clock out ports
    .clk_out1(clk0),     // output clk_out1
   // Clock in ports
    .clk_in1(clk)      // input clk_in1
);


 

endmodule
```

and testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module TB(
    );
    
    reg clk;
    wire clk0;
    
    top instance1 ( 
    .clk(clk),
    .clk0(clk0)
    );
    
    initial begin 
      
      clk = 0;
      
      
     end
     
always #10 clk = ~clk;
 
    
endmodule
```

result:

[image: behav. sim]

Comment: Did you config/connect FPGA PLL reset signal properly? A typical PLL application requires reset and lock signals to make sure PLL clock output starts from a known state.

Comment: Why do you want to change the clock?  There are extra complications associated; for example clock domain crossing.  Does the ram on your board not support 100 MHz?

Comment: @Mikef the part is not integrated on my board so I am connecting it on a breadboard with jumper cables. I think I'm going to have to further slow down the clock to about 2 MHz. However your answer solved my problem! after I waited for the locked signal and extended the simulation time it worked perfectly, thank you so much!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xilinx MMCM (multi clock manager) generated by clocking Wizard has an active high reset.
Reset must be asserted for several clocks then released so that the MMCM can synchronize itself.
After reset is released, then the MMCM can take 1000's of clocks to synchronize.
Your simulation may just need to run longer.

The MMCM has a locked output, which asserts when it is internally synchronized.
I recommend that this signal be instrumented in your testbench, so than you can see when it has obtained synchronization.

The MMCM simulation model generated by Vivado must be compiled as part of the simulation.

Some Xilinx IP need to have fine grain time scale for simulation.
Try timescale 1ps / 1ps.